# How to avoid explicit .isDefinedAt() call in pattern matching guard

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

I have some Akka-based actor system where multiple kind of actors is based on same template due to a fact that those actors only differ by a type of response value. For example:

```scala
final case class Request(data: Any)
final case class Response(data: Any)

abstract class ActorTemplate[T] extends Actor {
  def dataFunction: PartialFunction[Any, T]

  def respond(data: T): Response

  def receive: Receive = {
    case Request(data) if dataFunction.isDefinedAt(data) =>
      sender ! respond(dataFunction(data))
  }      
}
```

Partial function there is a method to avoid type erasure, which prevents me from simple

```scala
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Request(data: T) =>
      sender ! respond(data)
```

and at the same time force me to produce `if dataFunction.isDefinedAt(data)` guard on pattern and I simply don't like it very much.

Is there any means to avoid explicit guarding?

Only way I found for now is to introduce some silly extractor:

```scala
object DataExtractor {
  def unapply(data: Any): Option[T] =
    if (dataFunction.isDefinedAt(data)) Some(dataFunction(data)) else None
}

def receive: Receive = {
  case Request(DataExtractor(data) =>
    sender ! respond(data)
```

But maybe it is done already somewhere in standard library? Or maybe there is some other way similar to collections `collect` method, but for matching?

## Conclusion

After some thoughts I've went back to extractor object and moved it into a trait with help of @pagoda_5b suggestions:

```
trait PFExtract[T] {
 object PF {
   def unapply(any: Any)(implicit pf: PartialFunction[Any, T]): Option[T] =
     pf.lift(any)
 }
}
```

Comment: The type signature for `dataFunction` seems misspelled. It should be `PartialFunction[Any, T]`

Comment: pagoda_5b has good suggestions but your extractor is pretty nice too.

Comment: @sourcedelica Already 'pimped' it up with @pagoda5b .lift(..) suggestion:

`def unapply(key: Any): Option[K] = keyTransformer.lift(key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would actually do is use the `applyOrElse` method on `dataFunction`, defining a default response when the partial function is not defined for the given input

```
def defaultAnswer: T

def receive: Receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    sender ! respond(dataFunction.applyOrElse(data, defaultAnswer))
}
```

If you prefer to wrap your answer in a `Option`, there's already a method called `lift` that does that for you, as you correctly guessed

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    sender ! respond(dataFunction.lift(data))
}
```

You can even decide not to answer if the function is not defined for data

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    dataFunction.lift(data).foreach {
      sender ! respond(_)
    }
}
```

`foreach` defined on the `Option` type runs the code within the closure only if there's some content available (i.e. if you have a `Some(...)`)

Comment: Well, this are possible solutions, thank you! But:

1. only third solution works if we do not want to invoke `respond` with `None` or `defaultValue` at all;
2. while first two solutions provide some means to give `sender` some feedback about not applicable data, third one silently throws it out.

Then again -- thank you, those are food for thoughts.

Comment: @Seigert I suggested three solutions because from you post I wasn't sure what was your preferred way to handle "unexpected data".